# Conditional Probabilities- Lining up 12 blocks, of which 6 are black, 4 are red, 1 is white, and 1 is yellow.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A child has 12 blocks, of which 6 are black, 4 are red, 1 is white, and 1 is yellow. The
blocks are arranged randomly in a line. If no two black blocks are next to each other

(a) what is the probability that no two red blocks are next to each other?

(b) what is the probability that the white block is either the first or the last block in
the line?

a) the answer I got was $30/42.$ This is because I set the blocks up like this, where x= any color block other than black; B X B X B X B X B X B, with the final X block of any color being able to be inserted anywhere on the line, since it would satisfy there being no black blocks beside each other. The chance of choosing a red block as the last block to place would be $4/6$ and the chance of placing it beside another red block placed in one of the seven spots is $3/7$ so $3/7*4/6=12/42$ and then $42/42-12/32=30/42$

b) I got $2/7*1/6=1/21$ since there is a $1/6$ chance of choosing the white block as the last one to place and a $2/7$ chance that if it is selected that it will be placed in the first or last position.

Do these answers make sense or am I going about calculating these inccorectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I counted manually and you are correct. I get 150/210 and 10/210.